# postgresql subquery, count request

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am working on a project and I really do not know how to create this request. I have the following tables

```
create table drugs (
    drug_id serial not null,
    drug_name varchar not null,
    drug_composition varchar not null,
    
    primary key (drug_id),
    unique (drug_id),
    unique (drug_name)  
);
    
create table items (
    item_id varchar(50) not null,
    drug_id int not null,
    company_id int not null,
    
    price numeric not null check (price > 0),
    
    primary key (item_id),
    unique (item_id),
    unique (drug_id, company_id),
    
    foreign key (drug_id) references drugs(drug_id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key (company_id) references pharm_companies(company_id) on delete cascade
);
 
create table orders_items (
    order_id varchar(50) not null,
    inventory_id int not null, 
    quantity int not null check (quantity > 0),

    time_updated timestamp not null default now(),
    
    foreign key (inventory_id) references inventory(inventory_id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key (order_id) references orders(order_id) on delete cascade,
    
    unique(order_id, inventory_id)
);

create table inventory (
    inventory_id serial not null,
    warehouse_id int not null,
    
    item_id varchar not null,
    quantity int not null check (quantity >= 0),
    
    time_updated timestamp not null default now(),
    
    primary key (warehouse_id, item_id),
    unique (warehouse_id, item_id),
    unique (inventory_id),
        
    foreign key (warehouse_id) references warehouses(warehouse_id) on delete cascade,
    foreign key (item_id) references items(item_id) on delete cascade
);
```

I need to create a query that will get the most selling items. I have tried something like

```
SELECT 
  items.*, count(inventory.item_id) AS amount_of_sales 
FROM 
  orders_items 
  INNER JOIN inventory USING (inventory_id) 
  INNER JOIN items ON (inventory.item_id=items.item_id) 
GROUP BY 
  items.item_id 
ORDER BY 
  amount_of_sales DESC LIMIT 50
```

But eventually this does not work. Would really like to make it true

Comment: What do you mean "this does not work"?  How does it not work?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need unique constraints on a primary key.  The primary key is already unique.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect that you would need to sum the quantity instead of just counting rows:

```
SELECT i.*, SUM(quantity) AS amount_of_sales
FROM orders_items oi INNER JOIN
     inventory inv
     USING (inventory_id) INNER JOIN
     items i
     ON inv.item_id = i.item_id
GROUP BY i.item_id
ORDER BY amount_of_sales DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you only need the one table, `order_items`.  Are you looking for any other data to be included?  Total sale value is a likely candidate, which would require a join to `items` in your current design - but please read my warnings below before you implement that.

For your request as-is, you just want this:

```
SELECT inventory_id, SUM(quantity) AS items_sold 
FROM orders_items
ORDER BY items_sold
```

WARNING: Your tables have some referential issues.

First, time: You have a price in the `items` table, but no time frame.  This means if the item price ever changes, your historical reporting will be incorrect.

I would recommend including the price in the orders table `orders_items`.  This will make it easy and intuitive for any future reporting you generate, AND it will allow you to look at individual orders like a snapshot.

Second issue, cascading delete: Right now, if you delete an item from your `items` table, it will ripple out through your other tables, sniping their rows.  You almost certainly don't want to delete items for your typical core flow - you'll want to deactivate them.  The last thing you want is someone going "Oh, let me remove this from the catalogue" and then having it disappear from an active order and your warehousing inventory.

You can either add an active/inactive column to flag them, or you can add a starttime+endtime.  The starttime+endtime also helps solve the time issue above, but it's a bit more work, and I don't know how full this table might get.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer, I have used other query in order to achieve the task, but I did not think about delete cascade, thank you!